# send function's data to a variable

Tags: php

hello i have variable and a function. function get me current logged in user's full name and that works property with this code:

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
$fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login.php");
exit;
}

?>
Welcome back <?= $fgmembersite->UserFullName(); ?>!
```

now if i want to put function to a variable what i can do?

```
<?php
$job1 =' ?><?= $fgmembersite->UserFullName();' ?>
<?php 
echo "$job1";
?>
```

and my function is this:

```
function UserFullName()
{
    return isset($_SESSION['name_of_user'])?$_SESSION['name_of_user']:'';
}
```

the result is just: ?>UserFullName();

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$job1 = $fgmembersite->UserFullName();
?>
```

What did you tried is assign string value to a variable job

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// <--- maybe lots of other code here --->
$job1 = $fgmembersite->UserFullName();
// <--- maybe lots of other code here --->
?>
```

Comment: i forgot my main question: now i want send the value into a table in a database: "INSERT INTO $db_table (job_id,user_name) VALUES ('" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['job']) . "','$job1')"; it get me null in table :(

Comment: Then please add this part to your actual question. Spreading it out over the comments to (possibly many) answers is not a good idea.